# Crossmint/connect Vite integration issue

Tags: vite, crossmint

I'm trying to add Crossmint/connect to my Vite app, but got an error.
No any other code is used, just simple Vite react-ts app.

Note: @crossmint/client-sdk-react-ui is working fine.

Using:

- "vite": "^4.4.5",
- "@crossmint/connect": "^0.11.0-alpha.0",

Error log:

```
✘ [ERROR] Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)

    node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js:4:34:
      4 │     const fetch = /* #__PURE__ */ await import(/* webpackIgnore: true...
        ╵                                   ~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)

    node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js:5:39:
      5 │ ...t { Crypto } = /* #__PURE__ */ await import(/* webpackIgnore: true...
        ╵                                   ~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)

    node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js:6:42:
      6 │ ... WebSocket } = /* #__PURE__ */ await import(/* webpackIgnore: true...
        ╵                                   ~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)

    node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js:7:31:
      7 │     const fs = /* #__PURE__ */ await import(/* webpackIgnore: true */...
        ╵                                ~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)

    node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js:17:10:
      17 │ const C = await (async () => {
         ╵           ~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)

    node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js:32:10:
      32 │ const M = await (async () => {
         ╵           ~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)

    node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js:55:2:
      55 │   await Promise.all([
         ╵   ~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Could not read from file: /Users/.../node_modules/stream-browserify/web

    node_modules/fetch-blob/streams.cjs:14:40:
      14 │       Object.assign(globalThis, require('node:stream/web'))
         ╵                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

4:32:12 PM [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 8 errors:
node_modules/fetch-blob/streams.cjs:14:40: ERROR: Could not read from file: /Users/.../node_modules/stream-browserify/web
node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js:4:34: ERROR: Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)
node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js:5:39: ERROR: Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)
node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js:6:42: ERROR: Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)
node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js:7:31: ERROR: Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)
...
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/.../node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1649:15)
    at /Users/.../node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1058:25
    at /Users/.../node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1525:9
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Could you please take a look on it?